# Integral of $\sqrt{4 - x^2}$?

Tags: integration, roots, substitution

So, I've been struggling to solve the following exercise:

$$
\int_0^1 \sqrt{4-x^2}\,dx
$$

Most of the solutions I've seen online use substitution using $x = \cos(t)$ or $x = \sin(t)$, however I'm wondering how the substitution ***without*** $\cos$ or $\sin$ would work? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: A rational substitution can be $t^2=\frac{2-x}{2+x}$. Take into account that $\sqrt{4-x^2}=(2-x)\sqrt{\frac{2-x}{2+x}}$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. I suggest that you use `\cos` and `\sin` to get $\cos$ and $\sin$ respectively.

Comment: @spiralstotheleft, please add your comment as an answer.

Comment: Note this integral can also be calculated using integration by parts.

Comment: You can think of the question as asking the area of a part of a circle.

Answer (score 4):

Use the so-called Euler Substitution:
$$\sqrt{-x^2+4}=xt+2$$
See here
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution